# How to Format Excel Cells for Engineering Notation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

In the engineering disciplines it's nice to be able to have values formatted in easily readable engineering notation, where the exponent is a multiple of three.  How can this be accomplished in Excel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the cell formatting options create a new custom type for `##0.0E+0`.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this, but have the the multiples not appear as `.0E+3` for instance and instead appear as the typical unit prefixes `n`, `μ`, `m`, `k`, `M`, `G`, `T` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

To display a value with prefixes instead, one might do some formula massaging and end up with e.g.

```
=LEFT(TEXT(A1,"##0.0E+0"),FIND("E",TEXT(A1,"##0.0E+0"))-1) & MID("pnum kMGT",5+VALUE(MID(TEXT(A1,"##0.0E+0"),FIND("E",TEXT(A1,"##0.0E+0"))+1,100))/3,1) &"s"
```

... for a value in A1, that represents a time in seconds (as indicated by the last "s" in the formula).

Ref: https://physics.nist.gov/cuu/Units/prefixes.html

Comment: For localized version of Excel we can use the good [Excel Function Translator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889).

Comment: @MiBo "According to the NIST, pico is smaller than nano, so it come first in the order. " - yes, that is a typo, and that is more of a comment, not part of the answer.